# where are the member properties stored in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to export member properties like first name, last name from the database but I can't seem to find it.  I see that there is a loginUser table with the right columns, but it seems to only hold 5 entries instead of the full list of people that I see in the admin interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The member properties are stored in the `cmsPropertyData` table. The `contentNodeId` will correspond to the id of the member.

It may be easier to use the api to export your data. Umbraco uses the standard ASP.NET Membership Provider model. See [Membership providers](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers) for more details.

Answer (score 13):

Douglas is right, it's probably easier to access the membership provider.

But I worked on a project recently where we needed to do some querying for a rather large member base and the membership API was too slow, so we did the following view. Hope that helps:

```
SELECT        MEMBTYPEID.text AS MemberType, MEMBLST.nodeId, MEMBTYPES.Name AS MemberField, MEMBTYPES.Alias AS MemberFieldAlias, MEMB.LoginName, 
                         (CASE WHEN MEMBDATA.[dataInt] IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500), MEMBDATA.[dataInt]) ELSE MEMBDATA.[dataNvarchar] END) 
                         AS MemberData
FROM            dbo.umbracoNode AS MEMBTYPEID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.cmsContent AS MEMBLST ON MEMBLST.contentType = MEMBTYPEID.id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.cmsPropertyType AS MEMBTYPES ON MEMBTYPES.contentTypeId = MEMBLST.contentType INNER JOIN
                         dbo.cmsPropertyData AS MEMBDATA ON MEMBDATA.contentNodeId = MEMBLST.nodeId AND MEMBDATA.propertytypeid = MEMBTYPES.id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.cmsMember AS MEMB ON MEMB.nodeId = MEMBLST.nodeId
WHERE        (MEMBTYPEID.nodeObjectType = '9b5416fb-e72f-45a9-a07b-5a9a2709ce43')
```

The "where" clause just filters the nodes to be of type Member (I don't know if this GUID is constant for all implementations, please check first)

Comment: I did not have time to write a program using the API and this script saved my bacon. It dumps ever member with every attribute. Thank you so much!